# POSIX: Return value from write() on UDP socket

Tags: c, sockets, udp, posix

On a POSIX system, if `sock_fd` is an UDP socket, will `write(sock_fd, data, size)` always return `size` or -1? I.e., if `write()` does not fail, will the requested chunk of data **always** be written in its entirety, implying that, if the return value is not -1, then I can **always** ignore the actual return value?

It seems to me that this should be the case, but no man page seems to state it clearly.

EDIT: I suppose there are two possible answers. Either it is stated somewhere, but I haven't found it, or there is some obscure corner case that allows for the return value to be less that the requested size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike with TCP and other transports, UDP operates on whole datagrams only.

The return value of `write()`/`send()`/`sendto()` is the number of bytes accepted by the kernel for sending.  It is just that when sending a datagram over UDP, a whole datagram is sent at one time, or nothing is sent at all.  So the return value will always be the whole size of the datagram on success, or -1 on failure.  There is no in-between.

Same with receiving.  The return value of `read()`/`recv()`/`recvfrom()` is the number of bytes read into the user's buffer.  It is just that when receiving a datagram over UDP, you either receive a whole datagram at one time (and if your buffer is too small, the datagram will be truncated), or you don't receive anything at all.  So the return value will always be the size of the datagram copied into your buffer on success, or -1 on failure.  There is no in-between (not counting the possibility of peeking without reading, of course).

Comment: Ok, this makes sense to me, and backs up my understanding. Would be great, though, if you could point me to documentation (e.g., POSIX man page or UDP specification) where this implication is stated explicitly.

Comment: Not quite right. If your read buffer is too small, the datagram will be truncated, the remainder thrown away, and the return value will be, as always, the number of bytes actually transferred.

Comment: @EJP right, I keep forgetting that.  I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [UDP RFC](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc768.html) leaves the implementation details open:

> One possible  UDP/IP  interface  would return  the whole  internet
> datagram including all of the internet header in response to a receive
> operation. Such an interface  would  also allow  the UDP to pass  a
> full  internet datagram  complete  with header  to the IP to send.

The fact that the POSIX specs don´t go into detail either signifies, to me, that there is no *requirement* for UDP to use a specific implementation.

Having said that, I´m not aware of any UDP implementation that would handle partial datagrams.

Answer (score 0):

There is a return value in bytes. If it was intended to always write the amount you sent it, there wouldn't be a return value in bytes.

So treat it as if it could return anything and you won't have a problem.

Even if you just report an error in a log or abort the program, **CHECK THE RETURN**.

Comment: There needs to be a return value in bytes, because `write()` can be used for many things other than an UDP socket. So I don't think your argument, as you state it, is valid.

Comment: @KristianSpangsege If an API allows it, someone will do it. CHECK IT.

Comment: Right, but if it means that that somebody could not do it without breaking compliance with POSIX and/or UDP specification, then I don't care (at least for now) :-)

Comment: @KristianSpangsege but you've already spent more time asking than it would take to wrap all of your UDP write calls in checks.

Comment: You are making the error of assuming that you know why I am asking this question :-)