# How to write to a nonblocking socket (when using epoll)

Tags: c, linux, sockets, epoll

When doing async socket IO with epoll on non-blocking sockets, reading seems straightforward: Just `epoll_wait` until the socket is ready for reading, and read until you get `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK`.

But how do you send?  Presumably doing a single large `send` operation would block, so you will always get `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK`.  What are you meant to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably the kernel will not be able to send *all* data right away, that's why `send` on success returns *the number of bytes sent*. The important thing is that the number returned *can* (and most likely will) be lower than the total length specified in the call. You will only get `EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK` as an answer if *no bytes at all* can be sent. So when sending a large amount of data, you just need to correctly handle the (very likely) possibility that not all data is sent at once.

**Note**: this is different for datagram (UDP) sockets, since partial datagrams cannot be sent. See *[POSIX: Return value from write() on UDP socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50455967)* for more information.

Here's an example assuming a `SOCK_STREAM` (TCP) socket:

```c
size_t len;
size_t sent;
char *buf;

/* ... prepare data ... */

while (sent < len) {
    ssize_t n;

    if ((n = send(sockfd, buf + sent, len - sent, flags)) == -1) {
        if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK)
            continue;

        perror("send failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    sent += n;
}
```

Comment: Oh course it matters whether the socket is a datagram or bytestream socket.  Datagram sockets can't do partial writes, and use partial reads to indicate the datagram boundary.

Comment: To be abundantly clear, `send` (or `write`) on a file descriptor open in non-blocking mode will fail with `EAGAIN` / `EWOULDBLOCK` only in the event that no bytes at all can be transferred without blocking.  Also, a partial send does not imply that immediately trying to send the rest of the data would necessarily fail to send any.

Answer (score 3):

`send/to()` will send as many bytes as it can, returning how many bytes it was actually able to give the kernel to send.

If you are using a TCP socket, call `send()` in a loop until EITHER all of your bytes have been sent OR `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK` is reported.  In the latter case, stop the loop and cache the remaining bytes somewhere.

If you are using a UDP socket, `send/to()` can only send whole datagrams, so don't use a loop at all, and if `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK` is reported then cache the entire datagram.

Whenever `epoll` indicates a socket is writable, send any cached bytes/datagrams for that socket as needed, removing only successful bytes/datgrams from the cache, until EITHER the cache is cleared OR `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK` is reported.  Leave unsent bytes/datagrams in the cache.

Whenever you need to send new TCP bytes, or a new UDP datagram, if the socket's cache is not empty then append the bytes/datagram to the end of the cache and move on, otherwise attempt to send the bytes/datagram immediately, caching if `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK` is reported, as described above.